# BUG: bad unlock balance detected

Tags: python, linux

I try to run a python script on linux and I have the following error :

```
[  590.744579] =====================================
[  590.749299] [ BUG: bad unlock balance detected! ]
[  590.754024] 3.12.13-fslc+g1cd7a83 #11 Not tainted
[  590.758741] -------------------------------------
[  590.763460] python/296 is trying to release lock (&tty->legacy_mutex) at:
[  590.770317] [<c042ff7c>] tty_unlock+0x20/0x54
[  590.774687] but there are no more locks to release!
[  590.779573]
[  590.779573] other info that might help us debug this:
[  590.786122] 2 locks held by python/296:
[  590.789966]  #0:  (&tty->ldisc_sem){++++++}, at: [<c042fd90>] tty_ldisc_lock_pair_timeout+0x74/0x124
[  590.799193]  #1:  (&tty->legacy_mutex/1){+.+.+.}, at: [<c0296eec>] tty_ldisc_release+0x20/0x70
[  590.807921]
[  590.807921] stack backtrace:
[  590.812310] CPU: 0 PID: 296 Comm: python Not tainted 3.12.13-fslc+g1cd7a83 #11
[  590.819609] [<c0014914>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xe8) from [<c00120e4>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[  590.828208] [<c00120e4>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14) from [<c0060db4>] (print_unlock_imbalance_bug+0xb0/0xe0)
[  590.837743] [<c0060db4>] (print_unlock_imbalance_bug+0xb0/0xe0) from [<c0065170>] (lock_release+0xb0/0x208)
[  590.847542] [<c0065170>] (lock_release+0xb0/0x208) from [<c042d2c8>] (__mutex_unlock_slowpath+0x7c/0x158)
[  590.857156] [<c042d2c8>] (__mutex_unlock_slowpath+0x7c/0x158) from [<c042ff7c>] (tty_unlock+0x20/0x54)
[  590.866511] [<c042ff7c>] (tty_unlock+0x20/0x54) from [<c029ce48>] (gsm_cleanup_mux+0xf8/0x22c)
[  590.875165] [<c029ce48>] (gsm_cleanup_mux+0xf8/0x22c) from [<c029d388>] (gsmld_close+0x48/0xa4)
[  590.883914] [<c029d388>] (gsmld_close+0x48/0xa4) from [<c0296630>] (tty_ldisc_close.isra.1+0x4c/0x64)
[  590.893179] [<c0296630>] (tty_ldisc_close.isra.1+0x4c/0x64) from [<c0296658>] (tty_ldisc_kill+0x10/0x88)
[  590.902702] [<c0296658>] (tty_ldisc_kill+0x10/0x88) from [<c0296ef4>] (tty_ldisc_release+0x28/0x70)
[  590.911791] [<c0296ef4>] (tty_ldisc_release+0x28/0x70) from [<c028ff00>] (tty_release+0x3c4/0x4f8)
[  590.920803] [<c028ff00>] (tty_release+0x3c4/0x4f8) from [<c00d4658>] (__fput+0x90/0x1f8)
[  590.928947] [<c00d4658>] (__fput+0x90/0x1f8) from [<c0037684>] (task_work_run+0xa8/0xbc)
[  590.937081] [<c0037684>] (task_work_run+0xa8/0xbc) from [<c001d804>] (do_exit+0x2a0/0x8ac)
[  590.945383] [<c001d804>] (do_exit+0x2a0/0x8ac) from [<c001edcc>] (do_group_exit+0x3c/0xb0)
[  590.953688] [<c001edcc>] (do_group_exit+0x3c/0xb0) from [<c001ee50>] (__wake_up_parent+0x0/0x18)
```

In this code, I launch a program with `os.system("muxGWIO")` and latter I kill it with its PID (I have a function which search the PID) `os.kill(PID, signal.SIGTERM)`.

Do you have any idea how to resolve that?

***EDIT :***

I've more informations :
My `muxGWIO` program create 2 virtual com ports (I use the GSM0710 protocol to have 2 virtual com ports with one real com port). These two virtual ports are `/dev/ttyGSM1` and `/dev/ttyGSM2`.

I use them in my python script with : `com=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyGSM1')`

Then, later, I release them with : `com.close()`

and finally I kill `muxGWIO`. muxGWIO delete ttyGSM1 and ttyGSM2 when it's killed.

The bug appears at this moment.

If I comment `com=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyGSM1')` and `com.close()` lines, there are no more problems.

I think the problem is python don't unlock ttyGSM1 before I kill muxGWIO. So when python script ends, it try to release ttyGSM1 but it don't exist anymore.

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: What happens if you just run  `muxGWIO` from the shell?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I simply run muxGWIO from the shell and then kill it from the shell, everything works fine. The bug only appears with Python.

Comment: What happens if you run it from the shell, but it in the background, and later kill it using the PID?

Comment: Everything works fine, even if I run it in the background.